# JSP to display spring exceptions

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I'm working on `springMVC` with `JSP` view. In Spring controller data's are loaded into `POJO` and the `POJO` is added to Model's `addObject` method.

In `JSP`, form fields have name equivalent to `POJO` fields.

Question is how to display exceptions in my `JSP` page ?

I have a controller advice java file to catch all exceptions. I want to display the actual exception stack trace in my JSP page(at least for the dev phase).

Comment: Exceptions are objects like everything else; expose it to the JSP the same way you would any other data.

Comment: Like in the first case where you add your pojo in the model, you can do the same in the controller advice. Your controller advice can render a view so catch your message's exception, add it in the model and return the view.